# Obtener el evento al cancelar impresion

Tags: javascript, typescript

Es posible escuchar el clik cuando el usuario da click en cancelar, en la ventana de impresion del navegador?

Estoy creando una función y en el proceso de impresión oculto algunos elementos de la pagina para que solo se imprima lo que requiero, pero al dar cancelar o guardarlo como pdf, los elementos que al inicio oculte ya no aparecen, me gustaria escuchar los botones cancelar/guardar para proceder a desocultarlos y regresarlos a su estado anterior:

Todo lo estoy haciendo con *window.print*, aquí la función estoy usando Typescript, pero igual si usan JS para orientarme no hay problema

```
exportPdf()
{

   let nav = document.getElementById('nav-index');

   nav?.classList.add('d-none'); //ocultar navbar para no imprimirlo

   window.print();
   window.close();

   //Escuchar boton de guardar/ cancelar 
   if(btnCancel)
   {
     //Acciones
   }
   else
   {
     //Acciones
   }

}
```

puden probar haciendo ctrl + p es lo mismo que window.print(), estos son los botones que quiero escuchar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Existe el evento `afterprint` de `Window`, que se dispara cuando el usuario cierra el diálogo de impresión, pero no permite determinar la acción que realizó el usuario

Comment: Le daré un  vistazo, y hare algunas pruebas c:

Comment: @don_aman funcionó excelente, en typescript aparece como onbeforeprint (poco antes de cargar la pagina de impresion) y onafterprint (despues de cerrar la ventana de impresion), esta genial se puede manipular muy facil, puedes agregar tu comentario a forma de respuesta me funciono

Comment: Edite la pregunta para que integres la respuesta @don_aman

Comment: Pon la solución **como respuesta**, abajo, en el campo _Tu Respuesta_. Podrás recibir votos positivos y tú mismo puedes marcarla como aceptada unas horas después. De paso, otros sabrán que tu respuesta tuvo solución. O bueno, @don_aman podría escribir la respuesta también

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCION : Aporte por don_aman**

Dentro de la funcion agregue una funcion anonima que escuha los eventos antes y despues de cargar la pagina, se ejecuta unicamente al abrir/cerrar la pagina de impresion, por lo cual se puede manipular el ocultar/desocultar los elementos quedo así;

```
exportPdf()
{

   let nav = document.getElementById('nav-index');
         
   window.onbeforeprint = () => { //Antes de cargar la impresión
     nav?.classList.add('d-none');
   }

   window.onafterprint = () => { //Al cancelar/guardar la impresión
     nav?.classList.remove('d-none');
   }

   window.print();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

No se mucho de JavaScript, pero segun yo se respondio a esa pregunta aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970829/how-to-capture-the-click-event-on-the-default-print-menu-called-by-javascript-wi

Comment: Un enlace no es una respuesta. Te invito a leer [answer]. Si crees que la pregunta fue respondida en el sitio en inglés y la misma cumple las reglas del sitio, puedes hacer una traducción de la misma, siempre que menciones la fuente y autor de la misma. Saludos